# How to get a security hash algorithm for a certificate using Powershell

Tags: algorithm, powershell, sha1

I need to get a list of all the certificates with a particular hash algorithm.

First I tried retrieving SignatureAlgorithm as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select thumbprint, subject, SignatureAlgorithm
```

Which gave me `System.Security.Cryptography.Oid` as a value of `SignatureAlgorithm` column

I tried using FriendlyName

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select thumbprint, subject, SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName
```

But the above returned blank as a value for `SignatureAlgorithm`

How can I retrieve the readable value of `SignatureAlgorithm`? And also how do I select all the `SHA1` certificates using `Powershell`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Select-Object` are expecting names for the properties to show (since you didn't specify a parameter, you're using the 1st pos. which is `-Property`). There are no properties called `SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName`.

If you use a calculated property, you can design your own property where the value is the property `FriendlyName` inside the object's `SignatureAlgorithm`-property. Ex:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select thumbprint, subject, @{n="SignatureAlgorithm";e={$_.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName}}
```

(`n` is short for `name` (could also use `l or label`) and `e` is short for `expression`)

Comment: Thanks! How do I do that in `where` clause to select only those certs that have `sha1` algorithm?

Comment: Filter on those with a signaturealgorithm-value. `.. | where-object { $_.SignatureAlgorithm } | select....`